# i have a question about code below. i just don't know what do cv.imshow() commands in code?

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2 as cv

sekil=cv.imread('download.jpg')
points=[]

def clicks(click, x, y, flags, param):
    if click==cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        cv.circle(sekil, (x, y), 5, (0, 0, 0), -1)
        points.append((x, y))
        if len(points) >1:
            cv.line (sekil, points[-1], points[-2], (0, 0, 0), 2) 
        cv.imshow('sekil', sekil)

cv.imshow('sekil', sekil)
cv.setMouseCallback('sekil', clicks)

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows ()
```

My question is: what do `cv.imshow()` in line 12 and 14? What is the difference between them? And why if I don't write one of them my code works wrong?

if I delete line 12 code runs but there are any circles or lines. if I delete line 14 code doesn't work.

Comment: stop guessing, start reading. in this case, read the documentation of the function `cv.imshow`

Comment: Your code is working. And I can draw a lines too.

Answer (score 0):

*What do `cv.imshow()` in line 12 and 14? What is difference between them? And why if I don't write one of them my code works wrong?*

`cv.imshow()` displays an image in a window. You need to specify both, the window name ( `'sekil'` ) and the name of the created `cv` image object ( `sekil` ).

The difference between the `cv.imshow()` in lines 12 and 14 is as follows:

- the `cv.imshow()` in line 14 *CREATES* the window, because there is no window already there.
- the `cv.imshow()` in line 12 *UPDATES* the content of the already created window with the updated content of the image.

You can see that the mouse actions still update the content of the image using the code below with un-commented line 12, but you won't see this while clicking, because without the line 12 the image shown in the window isn't updated with the current version of the changed image with added points and lines.

```
import cv2 as cv

sekil=cv.imread('download.jpg')
points=[]

def clicks(click, x, y, flags, param):
    if click==cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        cv.circle(sekil, (x, y), 5, (0, 0, 0), -1)
        points.append((x, y))
        if len(points) >1:
            cv.line (sekil, points[-1], points[-2], (0, 0, 0), 2) 
        #cv.imshow('sekil', sekil)

cv.imshow('sekil', sekil)
cv.setMouseCallback('sekil', clicks)

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.imshow('sekil', sekil)

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows ()
```

The code without line 14 does not create any `cv` window, so there is no `'sekil'` named window there you can register a mouse click callback for and the code fails because of this to run.